# Flutter Pageview - scroll onTap to next or previous items

Tags: flutter

Given PageView allows showing next or previous items with viewPortFraction, how can we scroll between items if a user taps on one of them? Scrolling works if user drags the list with their finger, but I would like to enable onTap too.

```
  child: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ...widgetsList,
      ],
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: PageController(
        viewportFraction: 0.4,
        initialPage: 0,
      )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap each page in a `GestureDetector` and `onTap` use the `jumpToPage` or `animateToPage` to switch the page.
If you have elements on each page which can't be accessed anymore because of the `GestureDetector`, you may want to use the `Stack` Widget.

Just pass the current *pageNo* to the `animateToPage`.

Here an example with an wrapped `Container`, but you could pass the complete Page as a child too.

```dart
GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.white60,
          child: Text('show')),
      onTap: () {
          _pageController.animateToPage(pageNo,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.easeInOut);

          //// some alternative navigation:
          // _pageController.nextPage(
          //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          //     curve: Curves.easeOut);
          //
          //// alternative just jump
          // _pageController.jumpToPage(pageNo);
      },)
```